# Joining two tables with FULL JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables `master1` and `master2`:

```
insert into master1 
(name,address,books,laptop,id,college) values
(ratan,mg road,rajbook,hp,id334,xxx)
(sham,r t nagar,malbook,ibm,id335,xxx)
(ram,shiva road,kalbook,hp,id336,xxx)
(farooq,uday road,rabook,hp,id337,xxx)
(sharukh,kr road,kambook,sony,id338,xxx)

insert into master2
(nam,lappy,idd,coll) values
(ratan,hp,877,ratan college)
(ram,sony,877,ram college)
```

I want:

```
select name, address, books, laptop, id, college, nam, lappy
  from master1 LEFT JOIN master2
 where master1.college=master2.coll
```

Output should be:

```
(name,address,books,laptop,id,college,nam,lappy
(ratan,mg road,rajbook,hp,id334,xxx,keshav,hp)
(sham,r t nagar,malbook,ibm,id335,xxx,null,null)
(ram,shiva road,kalbook,hp,id336,xxx,null.null)
(farooq,uday road,rabook,hp,id337,xxx,null,null)
(sharukh,kr road,kambook,sony,id338,xxx,ram,sony)
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: You show a LEFT JOIN with no ON or USING clause; you need to add one.  What is the reason for mentioning FULL JOIN in the title?  It seems to be irrelevant to your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE` is incorrect and you're missing `ON` part of `JOIN` clause instead.

```
select name,address,books,laptop,id,college,nam,lappy
from master1
left join master2 on master1.college = master2.coll
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ON`

```
SELECT name,address,books,laptop,id,college,nam,lappy
FROM master1
LEFT OUTER JOIN master2
ON master1.college = master2.coll
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select name
      ,address
      ,books
      ,laptop
      ,id
      ,college
      ,nam
      ,lappy
From master1
LEFT JOIN master2 ON 
      master1.college=master2.coll
```

Your Left Join is wrong i have formatted like this

## [Joins Tutorial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

[LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/left-join-optimization.html)

And your output would be as follows

[image]

## [Working SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e5cc/3)